# How do I render markup for a css grid with Vue?

Tags: css, vue.js

I want to start using [css grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/). With grid, there is no `<tr>` element. [All top level children of a grid container become cells](https://gridbyexample.com/examples/example1/). The layout engine breaks them into lines based on their attributes, and the number of columns in the grid-template-columns rule. And there's the rub: without a `<tr>`, where do I put my `v-for`? Each iteration of `v-for` needs to generate *n* elements. I need a magic disappearing element that leaves no trace in the rendered output (no trace of itself, but renders all it's children). Does this exist? How do people deal with this?

Answer (score 4):

Ok found it. Here's a little record if anyone follows me here.

[**Put the `v-for` on a `template` element.**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-on-a-lt-template-gt)

Comment: Holy crap that's genius! Using a `<div>` rather than a `<template>` with `display: contents` works too but has poor browser support.